# Shell find и запуск команды, удаление расширения, манипуляция с {}

Tags: строки, shell, exec, find

Нужно вытянуть из mp4 в mp3 звуковую дорожку. В общем работает такое

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -b:a 192K -vn {}.mp4 \;
```

Но хотелось бы очистить (удалить) расширение mp4 а то на выходе, конечно получаю `.mp4.mp3`

Делал разными способами

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec echo {}#.mp4 \;
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec echo {{}#.mp4} \;
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec echo ${{}#.mp4} \;
```

Для теста, конечно, заменил команду, чтобы увидеть как будет очищаться расширение, но не получилось. Где моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, так:

```
$ find -name \*.mp4 -exec sh -c 'echo "вход: $1 выход: ${1%.mp4}.mp3"' -- '{}' \;
вход: ./файл.mp4 выход: ./файл.mp3
```

обратите внимание, что вторым аргументом программе *sh* передаётся строка в **одинарных** кавычках. это чтобы экземпляр оболочки, в котором вы запускаете команду, не пытался обрабатывать встречающиеся в строке `$1` и `${1%.mp4}`. если надо заключить всё-таки в двойные кавычки, то символ `$` надо будет «заэскейпить»: `\$`.

---

> Где моя ошибка?
>
> ```
> find . -name "*.mp4" -exec echo ${{}#.mp4} \;
> ```

ход мысли, в общем, правильный — воспользоваться [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). но:

1. программа *find* этого не умеет, а умеет программа, выполняющая функцию (posix-совместимой) оболочки, которую (программу) и надо явно вызвать (как в моём примере)
2. как явствует из самого названия («**parameter** expansion»), в конструкции должен присутствовать [**параметр**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (в терминологии стандарта posix — это имя переменной, номер аргумента или [спецсимвол](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)).

   - так: `${xyz%строка}` — можно (обрабатываться будет значение переменной `xyz`)
   - и так: `${1%строка}` — можно (обрабатываться будет первый аргумент)
   - а так: `${./файл.mp4%строка}` — нельзя (надеюсь, понятно, откуда появляется строка `./файл.mp4` — её подставит программа *find* вместо `{}`
3. ну и по мелочи: `${параметр#строка}` — удалит **префикс**, а вам надо **суффикс**: `${параметр%строка}`